# Never entering in cursor.moveToNext() in Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, android-sqlite

I'm trying Official Documentation for Android [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java). Creating Database, Table and inserting data is working fine. But I'm unable to get data from database. Here is the piece of code to retrieve data from table.

```
public Person searchDataInDB(String personCellString) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
    // you will actually use after this query.
    String[] projection = {
            PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_ID,
            PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,
            PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_NO,
            PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS
    };

    // Filter results WHERE "cell#" = 'Person Cell #'
    String selection = SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_NO + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"'" + personCellString + "'"};

    // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
    //  String sortOrder = SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
            null,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
            selection,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,          // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                   // don't group the rows
            null,                   // don't filter by row groups
            null               // The sort order
    );
    String [] names = cursor.getColumnNames();
    Log.e("SQLiteDB", "cursorCount = " + cursor.getCount() + ", cursorColumnCount = " + cursor.getColumnCount() + ", Column = " + names[0]);

    Person person = null;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = (int) cursor.getLong(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_ID));
        Log.e("SQLiteDB", "moveToNext id = " + id);
        String name = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_NAME));
        Log.e("SQLiteDB", "moveToNext name = " + name);
        String cellNo = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_NO));
        Log.e("SQLiteDB", "moveToNext cell = " + cellNo);
        String address = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLiteDBHelper.PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS));
        Log.e("SQLiteDB", "moveToNext address = " + address);
        person = new Person(id, name, cellNo, address);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return person;
}
```

It seems like my app does not enter in while loop i.e. `while(cursor.moveToNext()` So this method always returns initial value of person which is null. As a result, the first condition is always true from below code

```
Person person = dbHelper.searchDataInDB(personCellString);
     if (person == null) {
          Toast.makeText(mContext, "no such record exists in database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
         String personDetails = "Name = " + person.getName()
                  + "Cell Number = " + person.getCellNumber()
                  + "Address = " + person.getAddress();
         personDetailsTV.setText(personDetails);
     }
```

I'm using DB Browser for SQLite so I can see the records are successfully adding in the database.

What should I do with the above code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with this:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {"'" + personCellString + "'"};
```

is searching for the string value of `personCellString` enclosed inside single quotes and not for the actual value of the string `personCellString`.

Remove the single quotes:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {personCellString};
```

You don't have to worry about the string representation of `personCellString` in the final sql statement that will be constructed and executed which will contain them without explicitly setting them.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. I was confusing it with the native SQL query where we have to add quotes :). Thanks